# Error toggling removable device: Error opening sound device 0. No audio in Linux Mint VMWare Workstation 14 Player. No audio

Tags: virtual-machine, linux-mint, vmware-player, audio-device

I was increasing the sound in my Linux Mint (Guest) OS using the slider in the sound options from the taskbar, then suddenly my audio stopped and I got the following error:

Error toggling removable device: Error opening sound device 0.

A device ID has been used that is out of range for your system.

The sound connection control operation failed.

Following that, the sound icon disappeared from the taskbar. I tried restarting my Guest OS, removing the old sound device and again adding another one, also trying to put back the volume in the initial level. But nothing seems to be working. Whenever I try to connect the audio device, the same error comes up.

Please suggest what should be done to fix it, what files I need to modify and what outputs should I provide for further clarification.

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about programming within the scope defined for SO. You may want to try SuperUser or Unix/Linux instead.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by changing output on host